# how to remove ? from redirect('controller/function') from codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

When login is successful i want to redirect to  `redirect('signinup/loginsucess')`

I am running in localhost. When id do this i am getting to `?` in the link. I want to remove `?`

My query enable string is true and my  htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /kkci/
RewriteCond $1 ^(application|system|private|logs)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/access_denied/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteCond $1 ^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|public|assets|css|js|images)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: do you needquery enable strin to be true?

Comment: please help me city developers

Comment: query enable string is true in config /config.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

change it to

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
```

but do you need `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;` ?